# getCitiesAsOptions()

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, third-party-module

I try to get from collection, City ID and City Name, to put in module `Meanbee/Shippingrules` as new condition
All it's good but on multtiple select filed I get city iD-s, I supose to get name as Label and Id as Option.
[image]

```
class Meanbee_Shippingrules_Model_Rule_Condition_Source_City {
public function getCitiesAsOptions()    {
    $cityCollection = Mage::getModel('romcity/romcity')->getCollection();
    $cityCollection->addFieldToSelect('cityname', $cityname);
    $cityCollectionMetods = array();
    // LOg
    Mage::log($cityCollection->printLogQuery(true));

    foreach ($cityCollection as $cityName => $cityName) {
        $cityCollectionMetods[] = array(
            'label' => $cityName,
            'value' => $CityId
        );
    }

    return $cityCollectionMetods;
}
```

}

Where I am wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$cityCollection->addFieldToSelect(array('cityname', 'citiy_id'));
...
foreach ($cityCollection as $city) {
    $cityCollectionMetods[] = array(
        'label' => $city->getCityname(),
        'value' => $city->getCityId()
    );
}
```

Comment: Nope now, fileds is blank, I think first need to loop in city_id

Comment: @TudorMihai can you please log `foreach ($cityCollection as $city) { Mage::log($city->getData()`?

Comment: ` class Meanbee_Shippingrules_Model_Rule_Condition_Source_City {
 public function getCitiesAsOptions(){
  $cityCollection = Mage::getModel('romcity/romcity')->getCollection();

  foreach ($cityCollection as $city) { 
   Mage::log($city->getData());
  }
    }`

This is code now , but nothing genereated in var/logs
Note: logs are active

Comment: test.log not generated as well

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCityId() on null in /home/egygamer/public_html/app/code/community/Meanbee/Shippingrules/Model/Rule/Condition/Source/City.php on line 5

Comment: Line 5 :     $cityCollectionMetods[$city->getCityId()] = $city->getCityname();

Comment: It solved with your code @sv3n :) $cityCollection->addFieldToSelect(array('cityname', 'citiy_id')); SO happy

Comment: Can i ask you somthing in this code i whant to filter by states ID's , i have 15k cityes in database and all shows in filed. Let's say I want to filter by State ID's 2,3,4,6,7 . I think you have a quick solution.. Thanks

Comment: You can try `addFieldToFilter('region_id', array(2,3,4,6))`

Comment: -1 for what PLS?